# remove selected directories from C:\Users

Tags: powershell

I am interested in finding all the directories in the C:\Users directory. I know running "Get-ChildItem C:\Users" display all the directories under the C:\Users directory.

I am trying to write a script that would delete all the directories in C:\Users except for the admin's directory. Running Remove-Item C:\Users* will probably delete all the directories and that's not what I want.

Comment: C:\Users also contains `Default` and `Public`. You don't want to remove these

Comment: The directories or the accounts? Have a look at this function I made a while ago: [Delete Remote User Profile](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4908-delete-remote-user-profile). It queries `C:\Users` makes a selection from the users, the let's you choose which to delete. This is used on a domain environment with Active Directory, so you may not get the full experience if you don't have neither.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Get-Help Get-ChildItem -online
```

You'll find the latest and full parameter infomation.in the article, you'll find -Execlude and -Name parameter.

Then use the pipeline mark combine with the remove-item cmdlet, you'll achieve your goal, below just a safe example

```
# This is a safe command, this will get subdirectories without -Recurse parameter
Get-ChildItem -Exclude Admin -Name | Get-ChildItem
# This is danger
Get-ChildItem -Exclude Admin -Name | Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned Above do not Remove Public, Default, All users

So an example would be:

```
get-childitem -Path "C:\users" -Exclude "Administrator","Public","Default","All Users","Default User" -Force -Directory| Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

The `-exclude` tells it to not look for the foldernames you dont want it to

The `-force` says to look for hidden files and `-directory` says to look only at folders

Then `Remove-Item -Force -Recurse` the `-recurse` is because the directory is not empty.